# Adding Dropbox space to Ubuntu One Cloud

Tags: ubuntu-one, cloud, dropbox

I have a lot of GB from Dropbox cloud storage space: can I use it to increase my Ubuntu One cloud storage space? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

No, the two services are not inter-operable.

Comment: Can you telle me please the sources from which you get this information. Thanks.

Comment: @Oualid - [**This**](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) would help you better.

Comment: @Qualid - Dropbox and Ubuntu One are distinctly different services, though they offer the same basic function of providing cloud-based storage. (Google, Amazon and Microsoft also offer cloud-based storage services.) None of them will allow "pooling" of storage from other services. They will just tell you to add more storage on their service if that's what you're looking for. The technical difficulties of having all the cloud services having API hooks that would allow pooling and have that function seamlessly are not something they are going to invest in.

Comment: @tijybba: thank you. I posted my question there. Hope I'll get better answer.

Comment: @douggro: thank you. I understand there is no chance to get all these cloud services inter-operable in the near future.